# How to get col size for single row in java with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I need to get column size for each single row. Here I use two for loops. One is for row and one is for column. In second for loop, My aim is to print some statements. But my col size should vary based on each row. Please guide me if you have any ideas.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("moviegrid"));
WebElement tBody = table.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
List<WebElement> trows = tBody.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); //this will print total no of rows in body
List<WebElement> tcols = tBody.findElements(By.tagName("td"));  // this will print total of cols in body

for(i=0;i<trows.size();i++){

    for(j=0;j<tcols.size();j++){
        WebElement colsValue = tcols.get(j);
            if(colsValue.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(studName)){

                System.out.println("Printing statement");
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

How can I give condition in second loop based on row size?? If I give column.size(), then for every row, all columns will be executed. But I dont need that. I want to provide column size based on each row. Pls help me

Comment: @Check my answer and let me know if you still face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a Map where key will be rowIndex and value will be column size.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> rowColumnMap=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
rowColumnMap.put(0, 3);
rowColumnMap.put(1, 4);
rowColumnMap.put(2, 6);
```

2) Now you can write the looping like below:-

```
for(i=0;i<trows.size();i++){

    for(j=0;j<rowColumnMap.get(i);j++){
```

So, in above code inner loop will execute number of times that is specific to each row.

Generating Map dynamically, for example rows value may change:

```
for(int i=1;i<rows.size();i++){
rowColumnMap.put(i, (i%2==0)?2:3);
}
```

in above code I am generating a map dynamically based on rows count, for every odd row I am putting column size as 3 and for even I am putting 2.

Comment: No, you can generate map dynamically.

Comment: Ok tell me, whats your doubt ?

Comment: HashMap is the only suitable solution for your requirement. I can help you out in using it properly if you are able to tell me more on your requirement and what is not working in your case.

Comment: "How can I give condition in second loop based on row size??" : What condition you want in above question ?

Comment: There's no need to map the columns, just do what you need to do within the loop. Otherwise you have one loop to map everything and then another to navigate through the map.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#moviegrid tr"));
for (WebElement row : rows)
{
    List<WebElement> columns = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); // find all TDs in the current TR/row
    System.out.println("Number of columns: " + columns.size());
    for (WebElement column : columns)
    {
        // do stuff to each column (cell) in the row
        System.out.println("  Cell contents: " + column.getText().trim());
    }
}
```

If you aren't familiar with CSS Selectors

`#moviegrid tr` means find all `TR`s that are descendants of an element with ID (#) `moviegrid`

CSS Selectors are very powerful. I use them all the time. [CSS Selectors reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Comment: hey I tried this too..but in this example, every column will get executed for each single row. I want to execute row specific columns

Comment: You should update your question with a more detailed description of what you are trying to do. Give specific examples because I don't understand what you are trying to do. How do you determine what columns need to be executed? How is it passed? and so on...